# Validate two forms inside one form element with ParsleyJS

Tags: javascript, forms, kentico, parsley.js

I'm building two forms which will live on a single page on a Kentico website. kentico websites are wrapped in one single form field so I can't create individual form elements for each form on the page. The problem is parsleyJS will only allow you to pass a form to initialise it e.g. $("#form").parsley(); and I need to validate the forms independent of each other. Has anyone had this issue before? Can anyone recommend a workaround.

```js
$("#form").parsley();
```

```css
input{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.1/parsley.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form">
 <div class="form1">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" required>
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </div>
 <div class="form2">
  <input type="text" name="anotherInput" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get the results you want using the `group` option to validate only part of the fields in your form. This is used in [this example of a multi step form](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the forms independent of one another by using the class selector.

```
$(".form1").parsley();
$(".form2").parsley();
```

Comment: You can only pass a form to parsley it will not accept a class unless it is on a form.